# Any alternative to using .gif images in an animated background?

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a very simple website at the moment and right now I am using a .gif image as an animated background.

```
body, html{
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3F7rneL.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

It works, but I'm sure that the background will take some time to load, so I tried to change the gif to a gifv but it doesn't work.

Are there any other alternatives to have this animation as a background?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be using background image and background color both, which results into background color rendering until your image loads(like similar color somehow that won't distort the design)

using background image and color:

```
yourselector{
     background: #ccc url('images/yourgif.gif');
}
```

Or in your code just adding `background-color` property.

It's just an option.